# Changing LDAP password expiry time?

Tags: 10.04, networking, ldap, active-directory

I am running LDAP Samba PDC on Ubuntu 10.04 server. By default the LDAP account pasword expires in 45 days. I want to change it.

I've tried hard to find this setting in the LDAP conf files but I couldn't.
What conf file needs to be edited to make this change?

Answer (score 4):

The configuration parameter you are looking for is `pwdMaxAge` as described [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html). However, you need to observe that this parameter is given in seconds. Hence you need to calculate `number_of_days * 86400` if you want to specify a particular number of days.